# Finding alternative method call to avoid internal API

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm currently developing a template variable that is about the same as `${enclosing_method_arguments}` with some steroids.

As part of that, I investigated and I came up with this code:

```
public class Resolver extends TemplateVariableResolver {
    @Override
    protected String resolve(TemplateContext context) {
        IJavaElement element= ((CompilationUnitContext) context).findEnclosingElement(IJavaElement.METHOD);
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        IMethod method = (IMethod) element;

        try {
            String[] types = method.getParameterTypes();
            String[] arguments = method.getParameterNames();
            StringBuilder appender = new StringBuilder();

            appender.append(types[0]);
            appender.append(" ");
            appender.append(arguments[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                appender.append(", ");
                appender.append(types[i]);
                appender.append(" ");
                appender.append(arguments[i]);
            }

            return appender.toString();

        } catch (JavaModelException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

What that does (for now) is get the array of class names and array of variable names and output them in the same formatted way the method itself wrote.
It is still on first steps testing phase (I still need to add the variables processing).

So far it works great but there's a huge issue. According to Eclipse itself, `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.template.java.CompilationUnitContext` is internal API, so it shouldn't be used by outside code such as a plugin.

**My main question is:**
Please help me find an alternative API to get this same data from eclipse except it is part of the official API instead of being part of the internal API like how I made.

Comment: I can see you have built you own resolver, nice! IMHO you can live with using internal API. Especially when extending JDT which is often unavoidable. The main difficulty here would be prying out `ICompilationUnit` from `JavaContext`. I do not see any simple workarounds and I suspect that they would require much more code than you have already wrote. Leaving implementation as it is is fine unless CompilationUnitContext gets refactored heavily (which is unlikely). Then again you only use one simple internal method: `findEnclosingElement` which will be easy to rewrite if that happens.

Comment: @MichałGrzejszczak OK, thank you!